# Robot: assign variables in setup phase using Run Keywords

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to create a setup phase for a test case in which I assign variables.  I know in order to do multiple keywords I need to use `Run Keywords`, but is it possible to set variables when doing this? For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Case1
    [Setup]    Run Keywords
    ...            ${var1}=    Keyword1
    ...    AND     ${var2}=    Keyword2
```

obviously the above doesn't work because `${var1}` and `${var2}` are just treated as arguments to `Run Keywords`. Since they haven't been defined yet, setup fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot. Even though you added "using Run Keywords", this question has the same answer as [Is possible to create new variable in suite/test set up - Robot Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27792271/7432)

Comment: This seems bad, as it _forces_ unsavory use of gobal variables.

Comment: @MarkHu: not necessarily. You can create suite-level or even test-level variables. You're not forced into creating global variables.

Comment: This still seems bad, as it prevents the common idiom of `result_var =  kw_action` --so you are forced to store the results in globals, or suite-level or test-level variables,  which though a functional work-around, make it difficult to follow the logic.

Comment: @MarkHu: we’ll just have to disagree on that point. I think suite level variables are perfectly fine in tests, and of course, test level variables are also fine  no matter how you define them. Regardless, robot doesn’t support `result_var = kw_action` in setups so the point is moot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Set Suite Variable keywork to do that.

```
set suite variable  ${var1}  Hello World
```

You might need to escape the variable...

```
set suite variable  \${var1}  Hello World
```

From the builtin library documentation:

If a variable already exists within the new scope, its value will be overwritten. Otherwise a new variable is created. If a variable already exists within the current scope, the value can be left empty and the variable within the new scope gets the value within the current scope.

Comment: This only works for strings; you can't call a keyword and assign the result to a variable in this way.

Answer (score -1):

The question here why are you trying to do this?

The way I do it, if I want to call keywords and set their outputs in variables
to reuse them in my test suite, I do the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Library        BuiltIn
Suite Setup    Initialize Variables


*** Keywords ***
Initialize Variables
    ${Argument1} =   Set Variable   some_value
    ${output1} =     Keyword1    ${Argument1}
    ${output2} =     Keyword2
    ${output3} =     Keyword3    ${Argument1}   other_value

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    # Here you can use the variables that you initialized in the Suite Setup.
    Log   ${output1}
    Log   ${output2}
    Log   ${output3}

Test Case 2
    # Also here you can use the same variables.
    No Operation
```

Note: If you want to setup the variables for each test case, you can do it either in the settings section like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Test Setup   Initialize Variables
```

Or you can use the setting in the test case itself (same as what you did in your question)

```
Test Case 1
    [Setup]   Initialize Variables
```

Note that  "Initialize Variables" can take arguments as well if you need.